# Is there any way to get the name of an Knockout observable object?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am extending ko.observable to write values to local storage. I'd like to use the name of the variable as the key, so:

```
self.newObservable = ko.observable();    
self.newObservable.persistValue(25)
```

would persist the value in localStorage with a key of 'newObservable'. Is there a way to get the value 'newObservable'? I've tried using constructor.name but that just returns the type name of the variable i.e. 'String' or 'Number'.

Comment: Note that if you ever put this through a minifier, the variable name may change.  May or may not be a problem for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "name of an Knockout observable". Here it should be more obvious why it makes little sense:
`var tmp = ko.observable();
self.newObservable = tmp;
that.newObservable2 = tmp;`
You now have 2 "names"

Comment: @miensol I believe the OP wants to know the name of the variable that the `persistValue` function was called on, within the function itself.  IE `this` would be `newObservable` within `persistValue` (unless it's bound to something else elsewhere), but they need to get the _name_ of `newObservable` rather than a reference to it.

Comment: Hi James. Yes, that's exactly right - I'd like to get the name of the variable that calls persistValue(). Good point about minification, by the way - I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: The reason for your difficulties should be seen as a sign that you're placing too much responsibility on a single observable.  Relying upon the variable's own name (reflection) can create code that is hard to maintain, can't be minified, etc.  Consider solving the problem at a slightly higher level of abstraction.  The self object should probably be responsible for its own saving and loading using a couple of functions that interact with local storage.

Comment: If you minimize a view model to the level that its memebrs are minimized too data binding will fail, so thats not a option in MVVM anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to give the extended observable the refence to `this` like

Pseudo code (I would use .extend() on observable instead)

```
ViewModel = function() {    
    this.newObservable = ko.perstableObservable(this);
}

ko.perstableObservable = function(owner) {
   this.owner = owner;
   ...
};
```

Then you can itterate over `this` and find the observable reference

```
persistValue = function(value) {
   var name = null;
   for(var index in this.owner) {
      if(this.owner[index] === this) {
         name = index;
         break;
      }
   }
   ...
}
```